# Problem when install GAMSpy by pip in the terminal

Tags: python, pip

i am trying to install GAMPsy - a mathematical package through PyPI. The link of it is: (https://gamspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/installation.html). First, it seems that i have install it successful but when i import an run it, it has the error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'deprecated' from 'typing_extensions' (c:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\typing_extensions.py)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvVos.png)

When I uninstalled it and reinstall again by `pip install gamspy` in the terminal, it got the error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gampsy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for gampsy
```

Can someone help me to figure out this bug? Thanks in advance
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYile.png)

Answer (score 1):

You wrote package name incorrectly :)
On the image attached you have typo in package name.
Your command `pip install gampsy`
Correct one  `pip install gamspy`

Comment: Oops, you are right, i have fixed that bug. Sorry for my silly mistake

Comment: @CaoNgocLam at least accept the answer by clicking the `V` sign.